# fetching the 1st page of pdf as UIImage in ipad development

Tags: iphone, ipad, pdf, uiimageview, uiimage

In ipad development is there a way to get the 1st page of a pdf file as UIImage???
if u dont have the exact solution now can u tell me which way should I proceed??

I tried this function..but UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() returns nothing...

```
+(UIImage*) imageFromPDF:(CGPDFDocumentRef)pdf withPageNumber:(NSUInteger)pageNumber withScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    //if(pageNumber > 0 && pageNumber < CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf))
    //{
        CGPDFPageRef pdfPage = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf,pageNumber);
        CGRect tmpRect = CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(pdfPage,kCGPDFMediaBox);
        CGRect rect = CGRectMake(tmpRect.origin.x,tmpRect.origin.y,tmpRect.size.width*scale,tmpRect.size.height*scale);
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(rect.size);
        CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
        CGContextTranslateCTM(context,0,rect.size.height);
        CGContextScaleCTM(context,scale,-scale);
        CGContextDrawPDFPage(context,pdfPage);
        UIImage* pdfImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return pdfImage;
    //}
    //return nil;
}
```

Thanks
Shoeb

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a category I found on gist to do what you want:

https://gist.github.com/892868

Additionally, here is a post/answer from the past on SO:

[Rendering a CGPDFPage into a UIImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4639781/rendering-a-cgpdfpage-into-a-uiimage)

Comment: the catagory gives the strange link error createPDFDocumentWithName in UIImage+imageWithPdfNamed.o 
Symbols not found

Comment: Are you linking against any required libraries, such as CoreGraphics (I'm guessing on the required libs)?

Comment: Have you resolved your issue yet, or are you still seeing the link error? I would go through and make sure all required libraries are linked to in your project. Are you using a workspace with nested projects by any chance?

Comment: Hi shawnwall i am also trying same thumbnail generation but not at all finding how to make please give some suggestion on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652472/pdf-to-image-creation-in-ios this