# PDF to image creation in ios

Tags: iphone, ios, pdf, thumbnails

Hi Everyone I am trying to create PNG(thumbnail) images from the pdf for my app for that i used couple of answers from  the stackoverflow below code is i am using `-

-(void)pdfToImageConverter{

```
NSURL* pdfFileUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"ebook" ofType:@"pdf"]];
CGPDFDocumentRef pdf = CGPDFDocumentCreateWithURL((CFURLRef)pdfFileUrl);
CGPDFPageRef page;

CGRect aRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 200); // thumbnail size


NSUInteger totalNum = CGPDFDocumentGetNumberOfPages(pdf);

for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
    CGPDFPageRef myPageRef=CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i+1);
     aRect=CGPDFPageGetBoxRect(myPageRef, kCGPDFCropBox);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(383, 383*(aRect.size.height/aRect.size.width)));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    UIImage* thumbnailImage;
    //thumbnailImage=[[UIImage alloc] init];
    CGContextSaveGState(context);
    CGContextTranslateCTM(context, 0.0, aRect.size.height);
    CGContextScaleCTM(context, 1.0, -1.0);

    CGContextSetGrayFillColor(context, 1.0, 1.0);
    CGContextFillRect(context, aRect);

    // Grab the  PDF page
    page = CGPDFDocumentGetPage(pdf, i + 1);
    CGAffineTransform pdfTransform = CGPDFPageGetDrawingTransform(page, kCGPDFMediaBox, aRect, 0, true);
    // And apply the transform.
    CGContextConcatCTM(context, pdfTransform);
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationHigh); 
    CGContextSetRenderingIntent(context, kCGRenderingIntentDefault);
    CGContextDrawPDFPage(context, page);

    // Create the new UIImage from the context
    thumbnailImage = [UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext() retain];

    //Use thumbnailImage (e.g. drawing, saving it to a file, etc)

    CGContextRestoreGState(context);
    NSString *documentsPath=[[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject] stringByAppendingFormat:@"/page_%d.png",i+1];
    NSData *imagedata;//=[[NSData alloc] init];
    imagedata=[UIImagePNGRepresentation(thumbnailImage) retain];
    [thumbnailImage release];
    [imagedata writeToFile:documentsPath atomically:YES];
    [imagedata release];
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();   


}
CGPDFDocumentRelease(pdf);
UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"message" message:@"images creation completed" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
[alert release];
```

}`

**Problem:**Above code is working well in simulator and its working in device for creating some images(up to 30 thumbnails ).I used analyzer to check memory leaks but there is no leaks in above code but still  i am unable to create all the thumbnails.I am using ebook.pdf(300MB) which contains 1037 pages.so i need 1037 thumbnails.

**Question : **

1.Is any problem with the code?

2.What is the mistake i am doing in the above block of code?

3.Is there any other mechanism to create png images from the PDF?

Thanks in advance,your suggestions are more important for me.

Comment: The above code is working well while including the block of for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ... .... (process page ... ) ...
    [pool release];
} code

Comment: This is bit slow i am trying for another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A loop for thousand pages means you alloc memory for each page process and that chunk of memory is never reused until method ends. Obj-C memory management works that way, with an effective release of memory after each loop.

If you want to reuse memory for each iteration, use an independent NSAutoreleasePool

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++ ) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
    ... .... (process page ... ) ...
    [pool release];
}
```

Or, in the case you are using ARC:

```
for(int i = 0; i < totalNum; i++) {
    @autoreleasePool {
        .... (... process page ... ) ....
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response i followed NSAutoreleasepool alloc and dealloc but even that also not fully creating all the thumbnails.This time its creating up to 60 images.

Comment: I'm loosing something in your code. I cannot understand why are you beginning twice the Image Context. There are two lines with UIGraphicsBeginImageContext. And only one UIGraphicsEndImageContext. Perhaps one thousand graphics contexts initiated are too much memory allocated.

Comment: sorry Gabriel by mistake i written UIGraphicsBeginImageContext two times I modified my code please see my updated code.still it is causing crash.

Comment: +1 Hi Grabriel your answer is awesome its working well.But its taking lot of time to create 1000+ thumbnails,Is there any way to create thumbnail with smaller time.

Comment: Sorry ajay, I cannot help you with that optimization. But if the answer was ok for the original question, please accept it. So it will be found by other programmers.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this open source project; they're doing quite a good job of rending the PDF into a UIImage. https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF