# Thumbnail creation improvement in ios

Tags: ios, ipad, pdf, thumbnails

Hi every one Recently I achieved thumbnail image(png) creation from the pdf and you can see the [Thumbnail creation from PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8652472/pdf-to-image-creation-in-ios/8652641#8652641) post Now my problem is, It is taking time to create a thumbnail images when compared to download thumbnails from the server through wifi.Is there any better way to create the thumbnails bit faster.

Answer (score 1):

I notice you have the interpolation quality set to high. If you set it to low, it will likely render faster.

Comment: +1 Thanks for your answer it is more help for my work.I modified interpolation is low it looks little faster than previous one(kCGInterpolationHigh i used previously).can you tell me can i use kCGInterpolationNone for generating thumbnails much faster.

Comment: what is the difference between kCGInterpolationNone and kCGInterpolationLow.I cant find good result in the apple documentation.

Comment: From CGContext.h: enum CGInterpolationQuality {
    kCGInterpolationDefault = 0, /* Let the context decide. */
    kCGInterpolationNone = 1,  /* Never interpolate. */
    kCGInterpolationLow = 2,  /* Low quality, fast interpolation. */
    kCGInterpolationMedium = 4,  /* Medium quality, slower than kCGInterpolationLow. */
    kCGInterpolationHigh = 3  /* Highest quality, slower than kCGInterpolationMedium. */
};
Probably None = Nearest Neighbor, Low = Bilinear, High = Bicubic?

Comment: I tried all the possibilities which is available in the CGInterpolationQuality enum but stil its not so much faster.

Comment: What about turning off anti-aliasing for the context you're drawing into? It might not matter so much in a thumbnail. You can use CGContextSetShouldAntialias() to do that. The other question becomes - what is on your pages? If it's bitmapped images, it might not be possible to speed up if they have to be decompressed on every page draw.

Comment: The page fully filled with images.Any other approach or  solution for getting thumbnail which is having single page nearly 3MB very fast even image quality is lesser it doesnt matter for me.